# Mongoose find or findById doesn't fetch document when indexed field is updated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, indexing, model

We have a client model that has many fields in it, there is three indexes setup up for the client collection.

```
Client {
   _id: uniqueId, // indexed
   email: string  // indexed
   pI: {}
   ...
   ...
   isDeleted: {
     type: boolean,
     index: true
     default: false
   }
}
```

A sample of the client schema looks like this. It is there for so many years(multiple people worked on it) and all other logic build around works fine.

The issue is when we flip the `isDeleted` key, it flips to true. However, when we query the same document that just changed won't return results, using find or findById it says client not found. To restore a client we need to flip this key back to `false` and this way we can re-activate the client(client not found using ID, email).

**It is happening only for keys that are indexed, so I am not quite following what could be the issue? It is because we are updating the indexed fields**? However, using aggregation FW fetch all the results for the same key that is `true` or `false` i.e if we need active or deleted clients.

Comment: Try querying mongodb directly, to see if that returns the data or not

Comment: I tried that it doesn't work. I took dump from the collection and searched it does exist. The problem is why it is not finding the document using _id.

Comment: If you are able to get the document directly from mongodb, them something might be missing in mongoose config.

Comment: I am able to search document in the DB dump, but using DB query or any ORM it won't fetch any data. Not sure what is causing it as any indexed field changed it stopped working.

Comment: That's strange, the ORM's doesn't throw any error as well, right?

Comment: You can try sync indexes in mongoose https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-syncIndexes, and then query the db

Comment: It doesn't throw an error, just says unable to find the document and that exists in DB. Something is off with the index field only that makes MongoDB not reach this document.

Comment: I can only suggest you to get the query execution stats, and check whether the index scan is happening or not and if it does, does it matches the required document or not